# Python 2.0 gives -9/4 as -3? shouldnt it be -2?

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.0. I tried doing `-9/4` and was expecting the answer to be `-2`. However, it returns `-3`. Now `-9/4` is `-2.25` and I thought int type would round it up to `-2` instead of `-3`. When I do `int(-2.25)`, it returns `-2`. Can anyone please explain why `int(-9/4)` returns `-3` but `int(-2.25)` returns `-2`?

Comment: Integer division rounds towards negative infinity, `int()` rounds towards zero. Not a lot more to say about that

Comment: `-2.25 > -3` so python returns `-3`

Answer (score 2):

The two operations simply have different rounding modes.  From the `int()` documentation, ([reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int))

> If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.

Whereas division rounds down, ([reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations))

> Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the same type; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.